# Need help with partitions

Tags: 12.04, windows-8

I made a bootable USB and put it in my computer. Then I edited boot entry (added nomodeset) and it ran. I click on install Ubuntu and when it comes to partitions, I don't understand a thing. I have a 640gb hard drive, 32gb USB and another 4gb USB which contains the Ubuntu installation. Is it a good idea to use my 32gb USB for partition? Do I have to shrink a partition in Windows and then use it on Ubuntu? How do I know which partition is which? 
Thank you for help!

Comment: Is your hard disk have only one partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing you need to do is create empty space from within Windows by downsizing your Windows. It is best to do this on the 640 Gb hard disc and you need a 25 Gb or more. Depending on what you want to do with Ubuntu. If you want to use it to download and save lots of files or large files you need a bit more than 25 Gb.

At the point where the installer starts about partitioning you can then choose "use empty space" and have it install using the empty space. When you can a bit more experienced try different partitioning methods (most of us use '/', swap and '/home' as a setup).